# Chrome Extension that clicks a button on Twitch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, twitch

I'm a hobbyist java programmer that just started learning javascript to make this extension.

I'm trying to make an extension in chrome that will click the chat settings button by the chatbox on Twitch when I click the button in my extension.

I actually want it to click the points button but that button appears randomly so I'm testing it with the settings button instead.

I think it might be that the name of the class of the button is incorrect but I can't figure out the correct name. I would prefer not to use getElementsByID() because I have extensions that mess with the IDs.

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Twitch Point Clicker",
  "description": "This extension collects points on Twitch for you",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "tabs",
   "<all_urls>"
   ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Twitch Point Clicker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Twitch Point Clicker</h1>
    <button id="checkPage">Click Settings</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "utilities.js"});
    });
}
document.getElementById('checkPage').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

utilities.js

```
function clickButton() {
    var activityTab = document.getElementsByClassName("tw-icon__svg")[19];
    activityTab.click();
}

clickButton();
```

I don't get any error messages but the extension just does nothing when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

When I manually try to execute your `clickButton` method in the developer console, I get the following result:

```
>> document.getElementsByClassName("tw-icon__svg")[19].click()
TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[19].click is not a function
```

The element you seem to select by using this query is an svg element, which doesn't have this function. Its parent however is `click`able:

```
>> document.getElementsByClassName("tw-icon__svg")[19].parentNode.click()
// I can see the menu open
```

Comment: Ah, good catch. When I try to run the parentNode version I get:   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined at <anonymous>:1:52.    I think I just need another way of finding the element I'm looking for like using an XPath.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just extremely new to javascript and was misusing the dev console. Your solution does work. My problem now is that for some reason my utilities.js file does not show in the extension when I load it unpacked even though it is inside the folder. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using Bob's advice and doing troubleshooting. The main problem was referencing the correct element as he mentioned. I merged utilities.js with popup.js. Code looks like this.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Twitch Point Clicker",
    "description": "This extension collects points on Twitch for you",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Twitch Point Clicker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Twitch Point Clicker</h1>
    <button id="checkPage">Click Settings</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://www.twitch.tv/*"}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript( {code: "document.querySelectorAll(\"[data-a-target='chat-settings']\")[0].click();"});
    });
}
document.getElementById('checkPage').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```